# Why does my string from my JComboBox return as null

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, lwjgl, slick2d

**Tile Selection**

```
protected void myBox(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (patternList.getSelectedItem() != null) {
        System.out.println(patternList.getSelectedItem().toString());
        getImagePath();
    }

public String getImagePath(){
    jk = patternList.getSelectedItem().toString();
    System.out.println(jk);
    return jk;
}
```

**Boxes**

```
 public void TexDefine() throws SlickException, FileNotFoundException{
    TileSelection t = new TileSelection();
    Tex[171]= new Image(t.newSelection);
    textureCollecter();
}


    public int getN(int px, int oy){
    int n;
    if(p==0&&o==0){
        n = 0;
    }else if(p==0){
        n=oy*42;
    }else{
        n=(oy*42)+px;
    }
    return n;
}
if(in.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_G)){
        TileSelection t = new TileSelection();
        System.out.println(t.jk);
        /*TexTileRenderer(getN(p, o), returnImagePth());*/
    }
```

I apologise it for bieng messy, but i'm new to slick and a amatuer at java but can you please enlighten me with you genuisness how the String jk when getting transfered between the classes are becoming null. Why is this?

P.S Im using slick and lwjgl libarys just a heads up. Its messy because i have been fiddling around with it and trying to find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) for better help sooner, and your stacktrace

Comment: What line are you getting the null at? here: `jk = patternList.getSelectedItem().toString();
`?

Comment: Yes Jon, thats exactly the line i think, but its alright there but when it goes over to boxes.java thats when it appears as null.

Comment: wheres the call to `getImagePath` in Boxes.java? and please add the StackTrace of your NPE

Comment: David that gets triggered from when a new item has been selected in the JComboBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    TileSelection t = new TileSelection();
    System.out.println(t.jk);
```

At this point if you haven't selected a value/default value the selectedItem return null.

Set a default selected item in your `TileSelection` constructor and also assign `jk` in the constructor after you assign a default selected item:

```
patternList.setSelectedIndex(0);//sets first option in combobox to default value
jk=(String) patternList.getSelectedItem();
```

EDIT (This is also about the code before your edited the code for `TileSelection` out):

Also note **this is not a constructor**:

```
public void TileSelection(){
}
```

**constructors do not use `void` keyword**, thus **calling `TileSelection t = new TileSelection();` will not execute the method you want** to create the frame and combobox etc so of course `jk` will be `null` either drop the `void` to make this a valid constructor or do:

```
TileSelection t = new TileSelection().TileSelection();
```

though I'd say use a constructor rather which will then make this:

```
TileSelection t = new TileSelection();
```

a valid call to creating a new instance of `TileSelection`.

And if you followed the advice before my edit you can then:

```
System.out.println(t.jk);
```

Though it's not good practice to expose instance variables as `public`, but that's for another time. :)

Comment: Thanks you i think i have it solved now, it was the constructor. I say you are a Genuis. And i will have a look through when my program is finished and set some as private if they need to be.

Comment: @Capitals I'm glad you got it working. and oh what a pat on the shoulder that is for my ego :P